# Difference between target.url and url in Facebook graph api response in attachment.data

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Does anyone know if there is a difference between the key:value pair target.url:someURL and url:someURL in the response from FB containing attachments.data?

The call can for example be (GET):
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/me/home?fields=id,name,attachments

I have received several hundreds of responses, without finding any difference between these two keys.

Is it for future use perhaps?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There's no difference between them. The target includes the id of the object which could be used for further querying but there is no difference between the urls. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/story_attachment